# How to restart Command Prompt from Command Prompt

Tags: windows, command-line

I am trying to set up a remote build server for Continuous Integration with Visual Studio Online. I run an npm install to set up the environment, in my case, to install the `tns` tools, so I can then run `tns build`, but I get an error saying tns isn't a recognized command. I believe I need to restart Command Prompt to get it to recognize newly installed commands.

How do I do this from the command line?

I tried this:

> taskkill /IM cmd.exe

but I get an error saying `The system cannot find the path specified`.

## Update:

Here is the full output:

```
******************************************************************************
Starting task: Run TASKKILL /F /IM CMD.EXE /T
******************************************************************************
File name doesn't indicate a full path to a executable file.
Executing the following command-line. (workingFolder = C:\a\1\s)
"TASKKILL /F /IM CMD.EXE /T" 
Error message highlight pattern: 
Warning message highlight pattern: 
The system cannot find the path specified.
******************************************************************************
Finishing task: CmdLine
******************************************************************************
Task CmdLine failed. This caused the job to fail. Look at the logs for the task for more details.
```

## Update:

```
******************************************************************************
Starting task: Run C:\WINDOWS\system32\taskkill.exe /f /im * /t /fi "IMAGENAME eq cmd.exe"
******************************************************************************
File name doesn't indicate a full path to a executable file.
Executing the following command-line. (workingFolder = C:\a\1\s)
C:\WINDOWS\system32\taskkill.exe /f /im * /t /fi "IMAGENAME eq cmd.exe" 
Error message highlight pattern: 
Warning message highlight pattern: 
SUCCESS: The process with PID 2960 (child process of PID 2716) has been terminated.
ERROR: The process with PID 2944 (child process of PID 2716) could not be terminated.
Reason: The process cannot terminate itself.
SUCCESS: The process with PID 2716 (child process of PID 1364) has been terminated.
******************************************************************************
Finishing task: CmdLine
******************************************************************************
```

Comment: "Here is the full output:" the full output from what? Please add to your question the script that is calling task "CmdLine"

Comment: @DavidPostill It is the built in system of Visual Studio Team Services, so I am not sure exactly how it is being called. Most of the functionality is abstracted away from you.

Comment: "Look at the logs for the task for more details." - what's in the logs?

Comment: @DavidPostill I can't see any info not in the console, but [here](https://gist.github.com/georgeedwards/4c09a3a901acd6644ee1d080e11647f3) is the full log

Comment: I suppose there isn't a `cmd` shell open at this point. Your problem running `tns` is caused by something else. Not clear what.

Comment: Why not just open a new command prompt and close the current one. Like open cmd.exe then on the next like put an exit. And just by the way you do need to open a new instance of cmd.exe in order for updated local paths to apply

Comment: Sorry it would be start not open and really you could just have start and for ease of use I would put it in a batch file that you can just call from so you don't have to worry on clicking on the different Windows (because the new command prompt is focused to so you'd have to click on the old one to exit it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

> TASKKILL /F /IM CMD.EXE /T

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am afraid I still get the same error, I'll edit my question and add the full output.

Comment: The second one: `The system cannot find the path specified.`

Comment: The First one `ERROR: The process "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe" not found.` - this seems better, as it seems to have found taskill?

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards This? `C:\WINDOWS\system32\taskkill.exe /f /im * /t /fi "IMAGENAME eq cmd.exe"`

Comment: Hmm, I think this could be an issue, see my question update.

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards So, how did you fix the issue my friend?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a batch file to one of your local paths and put this code in it

```
Start
Exit
```

Then run the batch whenever you want to restart command prompt. It literally just opens a new command prompt and closes the old one. The reason for using a batch file to do it is because when you start the new window it is focused on top of the old one making the exit more difficult unless it's part of a running program.

I think the reason your code didn't work is because you're having a program try and close itself which is known to be buggy at best because it will start closing it then fail because there's no longer a program trying to close it. With the code above you're starting a new program and closing the old one